# SQL Join with condition, several results

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have exercise for SQL using Library database, on picture below You can see how some of tables are connected.

[image]

I need to return addressess of those adult members of library who has kids(juvenile) born before 1996. I have prepared SQL statement. 
Is this statement right? Probably not, there is option that addresses could be the same for various of members. I don't know how to aproach to this statement statement.

SQL Statement:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.street,a.city,a.state,a.zip FROM adult AS a
JOIN juvenile AS j
ON a.member_no = j.adult_member_no
WHERE YEAR(j.birth_date) < 1996
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.street, a.city, a.state, a.zip
FROM adult a JOIN
     juvenile j
     ON a.member_no = j.adult_member_no
WHERE YEAR(j.birth_date) < 1996;
```

Assuming the column and table names are correct, there is nothing *a priori* wrong with it.  It should do what you want.

Is it the best possible statement?  No.  The issue is that the query needs to do the `join` and then an aggregation (for the distinct).  Another way to write the query is closer to the statement of the question:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM adult a 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM juvenile j
              WHERE a.member_no = j.adult_member_no AND
                    YEAR(j.birth_date) < 1996
             );
```

You can describe this query as:  "Select adults who have a juvenile born before 1996."

Note that this version does not require `select distinct` (unless there are duplicates in the `adult` table, which is unlikely).  Technically, this form of join is called a "semi-join".  The "semi" is because it can stop at the first matching row.  Once an appropriate juvenile is found for a given adult, no more need to be found.

Comment: My statement is wrong, there is huge amount of "adults" who has the same address. About Yours second statement Is there any diffrence IF i will write SELECT * FROM juvenile instead of SELECT 1 FROM juvenile ?

This is just for perfomance ? Or it is irrelevant ?

Comment: @jadupl . . . It is irrelevant.  The argument to the `select` is ignored.